# edit data from web service android

Tags: android, web-services

Can we edit the data that we get from service before displaying it in list view. If yes how can i replace a specialcharcter from webservice to an image .

Kindly help me in this issue.

Regards,
Raghav

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer:
Yes.

It all depends on how you get your data and how you display your data. Since you are not supplying any code no one can really help you. 
When you parse your data just check for the different values you want to replace and replace them.

If you use pictures use for example [base64](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html). Available in API 8 and above however you can download the file and use it with lower APIs.